# JSON Schema conditionnal required depending on value

Tags: json, schema, ajv

I'm having issues with my JSON validations. I have 3 linked select boxes in my page and I need the validation to reflect what the UI shows.
The 3 select are:
 - Scope: can be `ScopeNational`, `ScopeRegional`, or `ScopeInternational`
 - Country: list of countries
 - Region: list of regions ("Europe", "Asia", etc)

In the schema, the selects are objects with two properties: "key" and "text", both are strings.

If scope is "ScopeNational", then "Country" and "Region" are required. If scope is "ScopeRegional", then only "Region" is required. Finally, if scope is "ScopeInternational", none of "Country" or "Region" are required.

I tried many config with `anyOf`, `oneOf` and `if-then-else` but I could not achieve this
Here's the last schema I tried, without success:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Linked scope",
    "default": null,
    "properties": {

      "scope": {
        "$id": "#/properties/scope",
        "title": "Project scope",
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Scope"
      },
      "country": {
        "$id": "#/properties/country",
        "title": "Country",
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Choice"
      },
      "region": {
        "$id": "#/properties/region",
        "title": "Region",
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Choice"
      }
    },
    "oneOf": [
      {
        "properties": {
          "scope": {
            "properties": {
              "key": {
                "const": "ScopeNational"
              }
            }
          },
          "country": {
            "required": [
              "key",
              "text"
            ]
          },
          "region": {
            "required": [
              "key",
              "text"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "properties": {
          "scope": {
            "properties": {
              "key": {
                "const": "ScopeRegional"
              }
            }
          },
          "region": {
            "required": [
              "key",
              "text"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "properties": {
          "scope": {
            "properties": {
              "key": {
                "const": "ScopeInternational"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "required": [
      "scope"
    ],
    "definitions": {
      "Choice": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "text": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "key",
          "text"
        ]
      },
      "Scope": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "ScopeNational",
              "ScopeRegional",
              "ScopeInternational"
            ]
          },
          "text": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "key",
          "text"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Thanks !

Comment: Could you please show us both a valid and an invalid JSON example?

Comment: @leadpony Yes absolutely

This would be valid:
```json
{
    "scope": {
        "key": "ScopeNational",
        "text": "National"
    },
    "country": {
        "key": "France",
        "text": "France"
    },
    "region": {
        "key": "Europe",
        "text": "Europe"
    }
}
```

This wouldn't:
```json
{
    "scope": {
        "key": "ScopeNational",
        "text": "National"
    },
    "country": {
        "key": null,
        "text": null
    },
    "region": {
        "key": "Europe",
        "text": "Europe"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly modified your schema as below.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Linked scope",
  "properties": {
    "scope": {
      "$id": "#/properties/scope",
      "title": "Project scope",
      "$ref": "#/definitions/Scope"
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "scope": {
          "properties": {
            "key": {
              "const": "ScopeNational"
            }
          }
        },
        "region": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Choice"
        },
        "country": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Choice"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "scope": {
          "properties": {
            "key": {
              "const": "ScopeRegional"
            }
          }
        },
        "region": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Choice"
        },
        "country": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/NullableChoice"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "scope": {
          "properties": {
            "key": {
              "const": "ScopeInternational"
            }
          }
        },
        "region": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/NullableChoice"
        },
        "country": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/NullableChoice"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "required": [
    "scope",
    "country",
    "region"
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "Choice": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "text": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "key",
        "text"
      ]
    },
    "NullableChoice": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "type": ["string", "null"]
        },
        "text": {
          "type": ["string", "null"]
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "key",
        "text"
      ]
    },
    "Scope": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "ScopeNational",
            "ScopeRegional",
            "ScopeInternational"
          ]
        },
        "text": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "key",
        "text"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now all of the properties are required and a new definition `NullableChoice` is added to the schema. Please note that `null` is a type like `string` and `number` in JSON Schema.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I see where I may have misunderstood how JSON schema works (I'm new to this). In my final JSON, scope, country and region will always be present, but key and text will be null depending of the choice made by the user. So I guess I should add/use a "string is not empty" constraint instead of a required ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it works as expected, I'll mark that as resolved. Thank you !